# undefined method `all' for Imageable:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem with rails 4 concerns. I wrote concern:

```
module Imageable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    belongs_to :imageable   
    has_many :images, foreign_key: 'imageable_id', dependent: :destroy
    # has_one :primary_image, ->( limit(1) ), foreign_key: imageable_id, class_name: 'Image'
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['source'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
    after_initialize :build_image
 end

 private
  def build_image
    self.build_imageable if self.imageable.present? && self.new_record?
    self.images.build if self.images.blank? && self.new_record?
  end
end
```

I have problem with my private build_image method. First line of this method throws error:

```
undefined method `all' for Imageable:Module
```

When this code was inside model not concern everything was ok. Any ideas?

Comment: How do u implement the concern to your model?

Comment: I write at the top of my model:   include Imageable

Comment: That was a naming conflict because I have imageable model in my app. I changed module name and now everything is fine. Thank's for help